# How to I get the running total from a graph?

Tags: ssrs-2008

Im working with SSRS 2008. I have a bar graph showing me the defect counts. I am showing them with ranges from days to weeks or even months. Above it I want to show how many defects are actually being shown. For example if I show a range for two days. On day one there was 3 defects. Then on day two there are 2 defects. As you can see the total is 5 defects over the two days. What expression could I use that will bring back this value?
Thanks in advance
Zack

Comment: Does changing the "range" affect your query, or are you setting visibility settings based on the "range"? Also, where do you want the total to be shown? In a textbox above the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RunningValue in your Value Expression:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!DefectCount.Value,Sum,"YourDataSetName")
```